# Openstack-Keystone failing to create tenant

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, keystone

1. I have installed keystone according to "openstack-install-guide-apt-havana.pdf" on ubuntu 12.04, but it's fails to create new tenant:

   > robbie@robbie-Controller:~$ sudo keystone tenant-create --name=admin
   >   **Expecting an auth URL via either --os-auth-url or env[OS_AUTH_URL]**

   I have export OS_AUTH_URL:

   > robbie@robbie-Controller:~$ env
   >   DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu OS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT=http:  //controller:35357/v2.0 LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8 PWD=/home/robbie GNOME_KEYRING_PID=2418 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=libappmenu.so COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu **OS_AUTH_URL=http: //controller:35357/v2.0**
2. I have also tried:

   > robbie@robbie-Controller:~$ sudo keystone tenant-create --name=admin --os-auth-url=OS_AUTH_URL=http:/ /controller:35357/v2.0
   >   usage: keystone [--version] [--timeout ] [--os-username ] [--os-password ] [--os-tenant-name ] [--os-tenant-id ] [--os-auth-url ] [--os-region-name ] [--os-identity-api-version ] [--os-token ] [--os-endpoint ] [--os-cacert ] [--insecure] [--os-cert ] [--os-key ] [--os-cache] [--force-new-token] [--stale-duration ]  ...                                 keystone: error: **unrecognized arguments: --os-auth-url=OS_AUTH_URL=http:// controller:35357/v2.0**

who can help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to set environment variables.

```
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://controller:35357/v2.0
```

If you want to pass it via an argument use:

```
 keystone tenant-create --name=admin --os-auth-url=http://controller:35357/v2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the same command as root, or use "sudo -E command" which carries over the environment variables, then it should work.